# How receive a $_GET

Tags: php, get, var

I'm using mod_rewrite to mask the address. Like 'contact' instead 'index.php?page=contact. I have a problem with the internal search engine on the page. 
Form of search engine:

```
<form id="search" action="search" method="GET">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" name = "co" id="s" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The result is:

```
 domainname.com/search?co=word
```

How receive this word? $ _GET ['co'] doesnt work. Just does not work:
    `<form id="search" action="index.php?page=search" method="GET">`

Comment: Fix your whitespace `name = "co"` should be `name="co"`. Though it may work for some browsers, it may not for all.

Comment: And what PHP are you using? Post your PHP code.  If, in fact you are using `$ _GET['co']` with a space after `$`, that won't work. Should be `$_GET['co']`

Comment: Could you show your url rewrite rule?

Comment: the problem possibly lies on the web server rewrite rule..
it removes the original query string..

Comment: here: http://pastebin.com/tpLrTVX2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write your html withouth spaces

```
<form id="search" action="search" method="GET">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="co" id="s" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

everything should work if you use `$_GET['co']`

Comment: I'm using without space, my php code
print_r($_GET);
$query = "SELECT * FROM sklad_portfolio WHERE news_header LIKE '%".$_GET['co']."%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

Comment: result array:
Only: Array ( [page] => search ) 
Adress: domain.com/search?co=test